# Changing the thickness of seekbar programmatically

Tags: android, nativescript, android-seekbar

I created a seekbar programmatically and I want to change the thickness of without xml styling.

`setLayoutParams` doesn't seem to work, neither does `setMinimumHeight` followed by an `invalidate()`.

I tried using the constructor with 3 params, setting the layout style to `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal` and then set the `LayoutParams`, still no luck.

Can anybody help me with this?

Note :The environment that I am using does not allow me to use xml ( https://www.nativescript.org/ ) , but everything that is possible in android programmatically, is possible using it.